# Camera Surveillance app save video to server

Tags: raspberry-pi, localhost, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am building a camera surveillance app in which my webcam is connected to raspberry pi.I am able to view my data live using "motion" package and also able to store the video recording with timestamp as file name. But its storing in raspberry Pi. I want that my data is stored in the server which is my localhost(my computer) and save the file for the time limit of 30 minutes and then create a new file with new timestamp automatically. How can I do it. any link or tutorial would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options to do it.
If you want record video all the time (not only if motion is detected), use option:

```
emulate_motion true
```

To specify max video length use option:

```
movie_max_time <time in seconds>
```

And finally, if you want to copy this video somewhere, you can specify script to be run after video is saved:

```
on_event_end <absolute path to your script>
```

You can pass some arguments to that script for example filename of video

```
%f
```